# What is the default behaviour of apport / whoopsie in 18.04 / 19.10 regarding crash reporting

Tags: 18.04, crash, 19.10, apport, whoopsie

When application crashes the Linux kernel sends the core dump to apport which then provides it to whoopsie. Would these servcies in stable distribution send crash reports (including core dumps) to Canonical for analysis?

As per my understanding apport doesn't send it by default (only for failures of type Bug / Package). It is still not clear regarding whoopsie behavior. According to wiki pages it seems that whoopsie would always ask user confirmation to send report. Does it do it regardless of failure type?

Answer (score 0):

In 18.04, I see an option in the Whoopsie dialog to make it send the bug automatically next time. By default (or at least the first time) it asks you for permission.

I see the flag when I click on the Advanced button.